# CSS: table column shifts as icon toggles visibility on hover

Tags: html, css

Here is plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/iwvjJcUurUW2AvkDArfz?p=preview

The problem is that when I hover on each row, the column shifts to the left, which is not desirable.

I want that the icons appear and disappear on mouse hover but table columns don't shift their positions

How can i achieve that?

Thank you

Comment: your HTML is not valid though

Comment: @diEcho, please elaborate, I do not understand where it is invalid

Comment: `thead` tag must be closed before `tbody`

Comment: see : http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/AaXbS/1

Comment: you haven't choose any answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your css:-

```
tr i.icon-minus-sign {visibility: hidden;}
tr:hover i.icon-minus-sign {visibility: visible;}
```

Issue is that you have a column without any element initially since it is `display:none` hence your other cells expand taking the space. when you hover over the element occupies space and your shrunk td's expand. To avoid this best thing is to use `visibility` which takes the element space even if it hidden unlike `display` property

Comment: what a timing, after posting this question, I was trying the same thing, got it working, updated the answer and saw your post :), Thank you @PSL anyways for quick response

Comment: Just saw your question and immediately realized it must be display v/s visibility issue.. :)

Comment: @daydreamer : You also can fix the issue only by writing valid HTML. :)

Comment: How is that possible, please guide

Answer (score 0):

add one more `th` and

```
<th>&nbsp;</th>
```

**tips:** assign width to all columns and also close `</thead>`

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th style="width:60%" >Name</th>
       <th style="width:30%">Amount</th>
       <th style="width:10%">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

[`Working Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/AaXbS/1)

Answer (score 0):

I got this here is the solution fix the `width` of `th` and also add one blank `th`

```
<th width="100px">Name</th>
<th width="300px">Amount</th>
<th width="100px">&nbsp;</th>
```

you can modify width according to your need that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working with CSS `visibility` property

Here is the updated plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/iwvjJcUurUW2AvkDArfz?p=preview

Here is all the did to my css

```
tr i.icon-minus-sign {visibility: hidden;}
tr:hover i.icon-minus-sign {visibility: visible;}
```